# Use of if function with &

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a formula like this. How can i do that?

`=if(p5>4,p5&H,"")` This didn't work. 
`=if(p5>4,p5,"")&H` this didn't work either.

What's the correct way of writing this? please.

I want the end result look like this: if p5=10 , then 10H.

if p5=3, then the cell should be **blank** without "H".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose literal strings in double quotes, so the formula should be:

```
=IF(P5>4,P5&"H","")
```